# angularjs one template with multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using UI-Router module to configure the States.  I got multiple states working and route to a controller (TasksCtrl) and render in a template (TasksPendingTable).  I need to have this template used by another controller (TaskSearchCtrl).  Is it possible?  Here is my States configuration.

```
/// <reference path="E:\Work\myApp\AngularSPA\AngularSPA\Views/TasksEndedTable.cshtml" />
/// <reference path="E:\Work\myApp\AngularSPA\AngularSPA\Views/TasksEndedTable.cshtml" />
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.filters', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider',
      function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider)
      {
        $stateProvider
            .state('tasksPending', {
              url: '/tasksPending',
              templateUrl: 'views/TasksPendingTable.cshtml',
              controller: 'TasksCtrl'
            })
            .state('tasksOverdue', {
              url: '/tasksOverdue',
              templateUrl: 'views/TasksPendingTable.cshtml',
              controller: 'TasksCtrl'
            })
            .state('tasksCompleted', {
              url: '/tasksCompleted',
              templateUrl: 'views/TasksPendingTable.cshtml',
              controller: 'TasksCtrl'
            })
            .state('tasksCancelled', {
              url: '/tasksCancelled',
              templateUrl: 'views/TasksPendingTable.cshtml',
              controller: 'TasksCtrl'
            })
            .state('taskSearchForm', {
              url: '/tasksSearchForm',
              templateUrl: 'views/taskSearch.cshtml',
              controller: 'TaskSearchCtrl'
            })
            .state('taskSearchResult', {
              url: '/tasksSearchResult',
              templateUrl: 'views/TasksPendingTable.cshtml',
              controller: 'TaskSearchCtrl'
            })
            .state('taskEdit', {
              url: '/tasks/:id/Edit',
              templateUrl: 'views/tasksEdit.cshtml',
              controller: 'TaskEditCtrl'
            })
            .state('taskAdd', {
              url: '/tasks/Add',
              templateUrl: 'views/taskAdd.cshtml',
              controller: 'TaskAddCtrl'
            })

            // Otherwise routes -----------------------------
            .state('otherwise', {
              url: '*path',
              templateUrl: 'views/404',
              controller: 'Error404Ctrl'
            });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

      }]);
```

Comment: Is it not working for you? What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have two controllers, then you should probably consider using a [provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), such as a factory or service, instead. Controllers can have multiple injected factories so you can contain most of your logic in the factories instead of inside the controller. [Here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide) is a style guide I always use when making Angular apps and it contains information on how to properly set up a factory. I hope this helps!

Comment: Oh and if you really want to use two controllers, then try adding another controller property in the state configuration. If that does not work, then you can always add the extra controller in the html instead. That should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

What I do if I need two controllers in the same route is defining two directives contained in different controllers and then use this two directives in the route that I want to define.